# cant work with gyroscope in Android

Tags: android, android-sensors, gyroscope

Im trying to work with gyroscope in Android.
this is my code

`//on the onCreate method
sensor = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);`

//the on onSensorChanged method
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
        if(sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE){
            Log.i("test", "TYPE_GYROSCOPE event");
                }
}

//the onResume method
protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Sensor Accel = sensor.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
        sensor.registerListener((SensorEventListener) this, Accel, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
}

But its not working, it's never getting in the Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE condition.

Comment: Your phone may not have gyroscope. You have to check for gyroscope before registerListener.

Comment: yes , I think that this is the problem